# Maven Release plugin fails without error message

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I just installed the maven-release-plugin on jenkins. I configured the plugin in the section Build enviroment with release:prepare release:perform as goal and -Dresume=false -DdryRun=true release:prepare as dry-run goal.

However if it comes to releasing the build, the build fails without any exception.

It seems it fails already at the preparing part.
The console just ends with:
    [INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) @ MeaBackupV2_Snippet ---
    [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Data\Programme\Jenkins\jobs\WebBackup-build-snippet-projet\workspace\pom.xml to C:\Data\Programme\Jenkins\jobs\WebBackup-build-snippet-projet\modules\com.mea-it$MeaBackupV2_Snippet\builds\2013-08-29_20-20-06\archive\com.mea-it\MeaBackupV2_Snippet\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\MeaBackupV2_Snippet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 4.025s
    [INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 29 20:20:15 CEST 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 16M/220M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    channel stopped
    Finished: FAILURE

Any help is appreciated, maybe I am missing something obvious, but the fact that there is no error message is not helping in resolving the problem.

Comment: add a -X to, and try running the same command from a terminal as the user that runs jenkins.